# DOMO - MYSQL Transformation Database table error

Tags: mysql, domo

I'm Trying to replicate queries on DOMO from microsoft acccess. I assumed I had got the correct syntax but now I'm getting a The database reported a syntax error. Not unique table/alias: 'ga_wip_due_within_one_week'

```
SELECT `egl_inv`.Category, `egl_inv`.StyleClass, `egl_inv`.StyleMaster,
  `egl_inv`.StyleMasterDesc, `egl_inv`.Color, `egl_inv`.ColorDesc, 
`egl_inv`.Size,`egl_inv`.GscSku, `egl_inv`.UPC, `egl_inv`.RedistributionFlag,
`egl_inv`.Date_Soldout, `egl_inv`.GGS, `egl_inv`.Core, `egl_inv`.CartonQty,
If(IsNull(`ga_inv`.SumOfQty=True),0,`ga_inv`.SumOfQty) AS GA_INV,
  If(IsNull(`ga_wip_due_within_one_week`.SumOfQty_Size_Open=True),
0,`ga_wip_due_within_one_week`.SumOfQty_Size_Open) AS GA_WIP,
If(IsNull(`ga_wip_due_within_one_week`.SumOfQty_Size_Open=True)
 ,0,`ga_wip_due_within_one_week`.`SumOfQty_Size_Open`.SumOfQty_Size) AS CUT,
If(IsNull(`averageweeklyfcst`=True),0,`averageweeklyfcst`) AS SS,
If(IsNull(`averageweeklyfcst`=True),0,`averageweeklyfcst`.`Demand`) AS 
Demand, If(IsNull(`openorder`.OpenOrders=True),0,`openorder`.OpenOrders) AS
OpenOrders, If(IsNull(`egl_inv`.SumOfQty=True),0,`egl_inv`.SumOfQty) AS
EGL_INV, 
If(IsNull(`averageweeklyfcst`.Demand=True),0,`averageweeklyfcst`.Demand) 
 AS AvgWklyFcst
FROM `averageweeklyfcst` 
RIGHT JOIN (OpenOrders RIGHT JOIN (((((`egl_inv`
LEFT JOIN `ga_inv`ON `egl_inv`.GscSku =     `ga_inv`.GscSku) 
 LEFT JOIN `ga_wip_due_within_one_week` ON `egl_inv`.GscSku =
`ga_wip_due_within_one_week`.GscSku) LEFT JOIN `ga_wip_due_within_one_week`
 ON `egl_inv`.GscSku = `ga_wip_due_within_one_week`.GscSku) 
 LEFT JOIN `averageweeklyfcst` ON `
egl_inv`.GscSku = `averageweeklyfcst`.GscSku) 
LEFT JOIN Demand ON `egl_inv`.GscSku = `averageweeklyfcst`.GscSku) ON 
`openorder`.GscSku = `egl_inv`.GscSku) ON 
`averageweeklyfcst`.GscSku = `egl_inv`.GscSku                
GROUP BY EGL_INV.Category, `egl_inv`.StyleClass, `egl_inv`.StyleMaster,
`egl_inv`.StyleMasterDesc, `egl_inv`.Color, `egl_inv`.ColorDesc,
`egl_inv`.Size, `egl_inv`.GscSku, `egl_inv`.UPC,
`egl_inv`.RedistributionFlag, `egl_inv`.Date_Soldout, `egl_inv`.GGS, 
`egl_inv`.Core, `egl_inv`.CartonQty,
If(IsNull(`ga_inv`.SumOfQty]=True),0,`ga_inv`.SumOfQty),
If(IsNull(`ga_wip_due_within_one_week`.SumOfQty_Size_Open=True),
0,`ga_wip_due_within_one_week`..SumOfQty_Size_Open),
If(IsNull(`ga_wip_due_within_one_week`.SumOfQty_Size_Open=True)
,0,`ga_wip_due_within_one_week`.SumOfQty_Size), 
If(IsNull(`averageweeklyfcst`=True),0,`averageweeklyfcst`), 
If(IsNull(`averageweeklyfcst`.Demand=True),0,`averageweeklyfcst`), 
If(IsNull(`openorder`.OpenOrders=True),0,`openorder`.OpenOrders), 
If(IsNull(`egl_inv`.`SumOfQty`=True),0,`egl_inv`.`SumOfQty`), 
If(IsNull(`averageweeklyfcst`.Demand=True),0,`averageweeklyfcst`.`Demand`);
```

The database reported a syntax error. Not unique table/alias: 'ga_wip_due_within_one_week'

Comment: I think your problem is that you are joining to the ga_wip_due_within_one_week table more than once without using any aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You have in the middle following line

```
 LEFT JOIN `ga_wip_due_within_one_week` ON `egl_inv`.GscSku =
`ga_wip_due_within_one_week`.GscSku) LEFT JOIN `ga_wip_due_within_one_week`
```

as you see you add both without an aliais for the second ad something like as
    `ga_wip_due_within_one_week_1` for the second

Comment: Thanks, yeah that fixed it...now I have a another error. The database reported a syntax error. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY `egl_inv`.Category, `egl_inv`.StyleClass, `egl_inv`.StyleMaster, `egl_i' at line 26

Comment: you wrote  GROUP BY EGL_INV.Category, it must be `egl_inv`.Category